# Xamarin - Android Binding Library - How to map callback parameter

Tags: c#, android, jquery, xamarin

I have to create a binding library from a file ".aar". One of the methods I have to map have a callback parameter:

```
public void mssEnroll(
                  @NonNull String mPassword,
                  @NonNull Context context,
                  @NonNull **AsyncTaskCompleteListener callback**
                )
public abstract interface AsyncTaskCompleteListener
{
   public abstract void onTaskComplete(MSSResult paramMSSResult);
}
```

How can I map this parameter in my c# Interface?

Any help would be appreciated.

THX

Comment: These  is  java code in your `.aar` file and you want use these method in  your `xamarin.android` project ?  Please elaborate a bit more. I don't get what you mean.

Comment: Sorry, I want to create a Xamarin.Forms plugin. Android Binding Library is used inside that plugin visual studio solution.

Comment: Is there any problem when you create a [C# interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface) ?

Comment: I don't know how can I map this method in my interface. How can manage the callback parameter in c#.

void mssEnroll(string mPassword, ???????)